# How to make a news feed like facebook for android?

Tags: android, facebook, feed

I want to make an app with something like facebooks news feed it's going to be a text with an image below it that opens a new page, but I actually don't know what it's called so I can't search the internet for something that I don't know it's name, so if someone can tell me what is it called or how to make a news feed like facebook or a tutorial for the idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is basically a ListView and ListAdapter.

You have to alter the default ListView Layout as per your need.

As per your requirement, to achieve Facebook Layout, you can follow this resource link for help

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

Answer (score 6):

You have to read about a `ListView` and `ListAdapter`. Base your solution on them.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an option, and the first step. You can use requests via JSON to search the texts and images stored on a web served.

```
// DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Your app");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("YOUR_PATH_URL_CONECT.PHP");

            try {



                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("value");


                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("thumbImage", jsonobject.getString("thumbImage"));
                    map.put("title", jsonobject.getString("title"));


                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();


                return;

        }
    }
```

YOUR_PATH_URL_CONECT.PHP

```
echo '{"value":'.json_encode($yourArrayJsonObject).'}';
```

Now do the rest of creating adapters.